# Switching theme in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, architect

I would like to change the color of my app based in different envs.
I'm using Sencha Architect 4.2.9
The app has only one theme and I saw in some places that we can have more than one them and load it dynamically in app.json, but I think it doesn't apply to Architect, just pure ExtJS coded apps, since the app.json is created again every time I build the app.
I've seen in Sencha Architect website that it's possible to have more than one, but just one can be applied at once. (https://docs.sencha.com/architect/4.2/guides/user_interface/application_styling.html#user_interface-_-application_styling_-_applying_themes)
So, is it possible to load different themes in Sencha Architect built apps?

I tried to create multiple themes an change it in the code.
I tried to change app.json, but it's not accessible in Sencha Architect itself and it's recreated in every build